# How to locate web elements which only gets visible after scrolling down the page in Java and Selenium

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver

**Code:**

```
List<WebElement> con =d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_2CIhCB']/h2"));
for(WebElement e:con) {
System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

**Output**:

```
Best of Electronics
Beauty, Food, Toys & more
Shop for a Cool Summer
Sports, Healthcare & more
```

It only prints 4 element text instead of 12 elements. In list only 4 element content is loading the rest of them are skipped. I used scroll method to scroll the page and load the element but it only printing 4.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads first time, only 4 elements are visible, as and when user scrolls down, the rest 13 elements will be loaded/visible on the page. Your automation script should imitate this i.e. scroll down slowly until all elements are visible. Only after that try to locate the elements and print it.

You can use below method to scroll down until it reaches the page footer.

```
public static void scrollSlowly(WebDriver driver){
    int j = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Brand Directory']")).getLocation().getY();
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++) {
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1)", "");
       j = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Brand Directory']")).getLocation().getY();
    }
}
```

You can call this method just before capturing the elements(see below):

```
scrollSlowly(driver);
List<WebElement> con = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_2CIhCB']/h2"));
```

**Full working code:**

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2doB4z']")).click();
scrollSlowly(driver);
List<WebElement> con = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_2CIhCB']/h2"));
    for (WebElement e : con) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
```

**Console Output:**

```
Best of Electronics
Beauty, Food, Toys & more
Shop for a Cool Summer
Sports, Healthcare & more
Home & Kitchen Essentials
Grooming, Books, Auto & more
Fashion Top Deals
Top Deals
Books, Toys & More
Pick Your Styles
Top Deals On TVs & Appliances
Beauty, Food & More
Fashion Best Sellers
```