# I'm getting stuck at 4 results when scrapping usernames

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api

So basically I'm writing a code to scrape usernames from linkedin's sales navigator. I'm using the following XPATH to export their usernames: `//span[@data-anonymize="person-name"]`. The issue here is that I'm only getting 4 results instead of 25.

I tried to use selenium's webdriver wait function to let the page load but even then the results are capped at only 4 names. What I'm expecting is 25 names to be output.

Here's a link to the filtered search I'm using: " https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people?query=(recentSearchParam%3A(id%3A2626510308%2CdoLogHistory%3Atrue)%2Cfilters%3AList((type%3ACURRENT_TITLE%2Cvalues%3AList((id%3A5805%2Ctext%3ABiochemist%2CselectionType%3AINCLUDED)))%2C(type%3AYEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE%2Cvalues%3AList((id%3A5%2Ctext%3AMore%2520than%252010%2520years%2CselectionType%3AINCLUDED)%2C(id%3A4%2Ctext%3A6%2520to%252010%2520years%2CselectionType%3AINCLUDED)))))&sessionId=uyd4f8NxTTa%2BMwuEtCEWmw%3D%3D "

Comment: A link to the linked in page would help us determine an issue

Comment: Sure, but you're going to need a premium account to access the link

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't work out the api calls that populate the page and just hit them directly?

Comment: Not really, the issue persists even after loading the page in. Could you maybe instead suggest another wait function I could use to let code run until the expected results have loaded in?

Comment: One of the reason could be that the page only loads 4 elements first, as and when the user scrolls down the page, other elements start getting visible. If this is the case, you need to scroll down slowly until all the 25 elements are visible and then try to scrape. Follow the solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/75811535/7598774. This is in Java, you can get an idea and write similar solution in Python.

Comment: THANKS! The issue was what you'd stated, it only loaded in 4 results. Just had to scroll down using selenium's inbuild scrollby function to pick up on the remaining results.